# How do you compare the results of two nunit test runs?

Tags: testing, nunit

We currently have a situation where several tests are failing. Someone is working on this, but it is not me. I have been tasked with other work. So I plan on running the tests in NUnit before I begin my work so I have a base line of failing tests and what the failure message is. I would like to use this result to verify that those tests fail with the exact same failure result while testing my own code. are there any resources that would allow me to do this?

**update**

I'm aware of the ExpectedException attribute. However that will not work for the tests that are failing the test condition. Also there are thousands of tests of which only about 100 tests are failing. I was hoping for something that would compare the two test runs and show me the differences.

Comment: Situations like these are the reason for the `XFAIL` test result specified by DejaGNU and other test frameworks. If NUnit supports it, change the expected result of all currently failing tests to fail.

Comment: Personally, I wonder how 100 tests could end up failing so quickly. Hopefully checkins are frequent and small in scope, so the possible number of broken tests would be small. Doesn't really help you at the moment, but is something to consider in the future.

Comment: They are integration tests and take about 3 hours to run. They aren't run by CI on check in. Also there is another project that acts a library to this one. It is stored as a binary in this projectd and only moved over once this project has been verified to work. I'm going to guess someone screwed up and accidentally checked in the binary. We currently do not have a QA team and the devs are managing this task themselves. All in all I would say we are doing a great job. FYI: 100 tests are only ~2% of the total tests we have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research while waiting on an answer. I found that the console runner produces xml output. I can use a diff tool to compare the two test runs and see which tests failed differently than the baseline test run.

Answer (score 0):

I'd throw an

```
[Ignore("SomeCustomStringICanFindLater")]
```

attribute on the failing tests until they are fixed.

See [IgnoreAttribute](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=ignore&r=2.5.10).

And try to convince your manager that a broken build should be everyone's top priority.

Comment: the broken build is the top priority, i stated in my question that someone, actually two people, are already looking at those tests. I was trying to avoid modifying the tests.